# Are there any browsers out there that don't drop my browsing session?

Tags: browser

I own a Samsung Galaxy S3 ( rooted, not custom-rommed, and running kernel 4.3 ), and often, I would be browsing an interesting site, or an article, and I would get back to work ( hehe ;). Hours later, to my chagrin, I would find that my browser dropped my browsing session, and I'd have no idea on how I landed on said article. Currently, I'm using worst-of-the-worst stock browser, Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Dolphin, and InBrowser, and the closest to do this is Opera. The problem that I have with Opera, is that when I'm browsing privately, the problem I just described happens within ten minutes of switching to another task.

Comment: Set a bookmark before going to sleep. I'm assuming you're working for the government.

Comment: In Firefox, do you set your tabs to"always restore"?

Comment: App suggestions/recommendations are off-topic here (see [help/on-topic] to know more).  I recommend an edit since the question does have on-topic issue.

Comment: @ott: I'm not sure whether to take your assumption as a complement or an insult.

Comment: @xangua: When using firefox, I do set it to restore tabs, but a) firefox is a memory hog, which is why I no longer use it, b) when it restores tabs, it seems to forget some of them and duplicate others.

Comment: @Firelord: Lamentations. -_- Where should I move the question to?